# Project ERROR: You need to set the ANDROID_NDK_ROOT environment variable to point to your Android NDK

Tags: android, qt5

I am trying to install the `mqtt` module to android_armv7. To do this, I create a folder named *build* and run this: `~/Qt/5.12.4/android_armv7/bin/qmake qmake -r ..`. Unfortunately I recieve this error:

```
Project ERROR: You need to set the ANDROID_NDK_ROOT environment variable to point to your Android NDK.
Could not read qmake configuration file /home/stefan/Qt/5.12.4/android_armv7/mkspecs/android-clang/qmake.conf.
Error processing project file: ../qtmqtt.pro
```

I have tried going to *tools->External->Configure->Environment->External Tools->Update Translations* and wrote: 
*"ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/home/stefan/Downloads/android-ndk-r19c/android-ndk-r19c
PATH="*
 in the Environment Change section. It didn't work. A strange thing (for me) is that I can deploy an application (without mqtt) on android_armv7. I am using Linux. What should I do now?